# Create LINQ expression for projections with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, linq, automapper, projection

I would use [AutoMapper](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper) to create an expression to use with LINQ (e.g. LINQ To SQL):

```
void Main()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonDto>();
    Mapper.Engine.CreateMapExpression<Person, PersonDto>().ToString().Dump();
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Person> Children { get; set; }
}

public class PersonDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<PersonDto> Children { get; set; }
}
```

But a [StackOverflowException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx) occurs mapping the "Children" property (I had already written to [Jimmy](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/category/automapper/) in the past).

Comment: what's the problem? How is it relevant?

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov is not possible to have the expression.

Comment: @MatteoMigliore if you don't use `IEnumerable` its work?

Comment: Yes, but it's not IEnumerable but IEnumerable<T> (I fixed the code I posted), the same problem with T[].

Comment: @MatteoMigliore I'm afraid hardly anyone help you, except Author of `AutoMapper`

Comment: Another tool that allows to dynamically create LINQ projections should be good! :)

Comment: I am having the same issue. Has a solution been provided by AutoMapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author told that the problem is that the root class has a self reference, but it's not supported by many LINQ providers.

If the root class has not self-references the problem is another with AutoMapper 3,
because the produced LINQ expression is:

```
x => new PersonDto() { Name = x.Name, Children = x.Children.Select(y => new AddressDto { Name = y.Name })}
```

Instead of:

```
x => new PersonDto() { Name = x.Name, Children = IIF((x.Children == null), null, x.Children.Select(y => new AddressDto { Name = y.Name }))}
```

So if the child property of the root class is null, the projection will fail.

At the moment is not possible to use AutoMapper for this purpose.